# Does Heroku Connect support Attachments?

Tags: heroku, heroku-connect

[Heroku Connect](https://www.heroku.com/connect) does bi-drectional replication between Salesforce and Heroku PostgreSQL. I have a free edition to do some testing and this has been working well so far with standard and custom objects. But when I try to map `Attachment` I get this error dialog:

> Unable to load fields for Salesforce object 'Attachment' of
>   connection: 2873. Internal Server Error. Status code: 500 (Internal
>   Server Error)

Does anyone have a setup with `Attachment` working?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I posted a support request on this problem and it is now fixed inside 24 hours. So **Attachment is supported**.

I asked for an explanation of the problem and this is it:

> In order to present the list of fields for you to configure your
>   mapping, Connect asks your Salesforce organization for schema
>   information. To reduce the number of API calls it caches this
>   information for all objects.
>
> In this particular case the cached schema for one of the objects was
>   blank - this was likely caused by a transient error at the time of
>   caching (perhaps the a network error when calling the API), but meant
>   that when you tried to create a new mapping the blank information was
>   causing the (not particularly helpful) error message you were seeing.
>
> By forcing the cache to refresh the correct schema information was
>   loaded which then fixed the issue for you. I've notified the
>   development team of the problem so that they can implement a fix so
>   that this doesn't happen in future.

Answer (score 2):

Definitely not supported as of May 2017 because Bulk API does not support Base64 data: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-connect-database-tables

The thing is you might see it work some time because I don't believe Heroku Connect uses the Bulk API every time. I think it tries to use the SOAP API before switching to Bulk. So to me you are rolling the dice by using these objects.

Base64 binary fields

Binary files stored in Attachment, Document and Scontrol objects use a Base64 encoded binary data type. This data type is currently unsupported in the Bulk API and is therefore also unsupported by Heroku Connect.

Answer (score 0):

According to the heroku connect docs, attachments are not supported.

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/herokuconnect#base64-binary-fields

> Base64 binary fields
>
> Binary files stored in Attachment, Document and Scontrol objects use a Base64 encoded binary data type. This data type is currently unsupported in the Bulk API and is therefore also unsupported by Heroku Connect.